# custom config file error

Tags: cakephp

I want to a create a config file for site configuration. I create `config.php` and put it into the `Config` folder. It's its content:

```
<?php
Configure::write('Title', 'My App');
Configure::write('Categories', array(
    'Recipes' => 
        array('url' => '/recipe', 'max' => 10),
    'Foods' => 
        array('url' => '/food', 'max' => 5)
));
```

And put this code at the end of `bootstrap.php`:

```
Configure::load('config');
```

But cake returns this error:

> ```
> No variable $config found in ...........\app\Config\config.php.php
>
> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
>
> Stack Trace
>
>     CORE\Cake\Core\Configure.php line 272 → PhpReader->read(string)
>     APP\Config\bootstrap.php line 110 → Configure::load(string)
>     CORE\Cake\Core\Configure.php line 92 → include(string)
>     CORE\Cake\bootstrap.php line 142 → Configure::bootstrap(boolean)
>     APP\webroot\index.php line 79 → include(string)
> ```

What's the problem??

**Note:** I'm using the latest version: 2.2.1 Stable

Comment: For **CakePHP 3.4 and above** refer this link => [Accessing Configuration::read in Controller in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23268668/5038388)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config file you should be using an array variable called `$config` instead of Configure::write if you want to use `load()` with the default PhpReader. See [API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/configure#method-Configureload)

Ex.

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'Title' => 'MyApp',
    ...
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#built-in-configuration-readers

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to use `Configure::write` which function is needed? Should I put `Configure::config('config')`? Generally, what's the best and standard way to have a app configuration file in cake?

Comment: That's what `bootstrap.php` is for. If you want it in a separate file, probably just using `include config.php` in `bootstrap.php` would be simplest. I'm not sure of another way.

Comment: exactly - load() with arrays and include/require with Configure::write()