# Accessing Configuration::read in Controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration

I have a separate config file for my CakePHP application which is loaded in the bootstrap.php. My question is, how can I access the Configuration's variables in my Controller? I.e. How can I perform the Configure::read('variable') function in Controller? Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand your question - you already gave the answer. Simply by using `Configure::read('variable')` in your controller you are accessing it as you wanted to. You just need to make sure you load your custom config files.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the silly question. I've missed something earlier I'm sure, but it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation.
There it is explained quite well how to load custom config files:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#loading-configuration-files

By default, as documented in the class itself, it will merge its configs with the already loaded configs.

```
Configure::read('variable')
```

then loads the content of the new config if it overwrites the app one.

Answer (score 4):

In my custom config file `/app/Config/myconfig.php` I define my config variables:

```
<?php

$config = array(
    'variable' => 'myValue'
);
```

In my Action I read can read the config file and get access of the variables:

```
Configure::load('myconfig', 'default');
$configValue = Configure::read('variable');
echo $configValue;  // myValue
```

Answer (score 3):

like this:

app/Config/example.php

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'MyConf' => array(
        'secret' => '1234',
        )
);
```

in your controller

```
Configure::load('example');
Configure::read('MyConf.secret');
```

Comment: **Don't forget** to add `use Cake\Core\Configure;` on **top of your controller**, otherwise, you will get following error _Class 'Configure' Not Found_

Answer (score 3):

Here i have found another good solution.[click here](http://www.fullybaked.co.uk/articles/custom-configure-files-in-cakephp)

Create a custom config
First off, create a file in the `app/config` directory named however you want.

```
Example: my_app_settings.php
```

Now in this file you can add any settings you want using the `$config` array

```
    <?php
    $config['MyApp']['mysql_user'] = 'bob';
    $config['MyApp']['mysql_pass'] = 'foobar';

// etc etc
```

Next up, you need to tell your app to load this new config file. I tend to do it in the bootstrap.php to ensure it is loaded throughout the app (although if there is a better/more advisable place be sure to let me know)

```
<?php
// app/config/bootstrap.php

// snip

Configure::load('my_app_settings');
```

Now anywhere in your app you have access to your custom settings

```
<?php
$mysqlUser = Configure::read('MyApp.mysql_user');
```